# 5 star feedback form

Tags: php, html

Solution found [Here](http://www.cssscript.com/simple-5-star-rating-system-with-css-and-html-radios/)

Live Finished Preview [Here](http://rbgraphix.co.uk/feedback.php)

If anybody requires help doing the same or similar please feel free to ask id be happy to help

I have created a 5 star feedback system that submits the data to a database in SQL. All works well and how I want it, except in the form. I currently have 5 ratio buttons that submit the selected rating number but instead I would like them to be an image of my personalized stars

And

When the user selects 1 star it changes to my 2nd star image, when they select more it changes the other stars up to the number of stars they selected

Here Is a [Live Preview](http://rbgraphix.co.uk/feedback.php)
and my current code for the ratio buttons

```
<div class="rating">
<label class="rating">1
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="ratingbtn" value="1" <?php if (isset($rating) && $rating=="1") echo "checked";?>>
    2 </label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" <?php if (isset($rating) && $rating=="2") echo "checked";?> value="2">
  3
  <input type="radio" name="rating" <?php if (isset($rating) && $rating=="3") echo "checked";?> value="3">
  <label> 4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" <?php if (isset($rating) && $rating=="4") echo "checked";?> value="4">
  <label>5</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" <?php if (isset($rating) && $rating=="5") echo "checked";?> value="5">
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered JQuery / JavaScript for handling the click events when stars are selected?

Comment: you need spam protecting the form will be hammered

Comment: Ye have considered it but don't know much about either so don't know where would start any ideas?

also was going to add spam protection once code is complete thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Your markup should look like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="star belowchecked">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
    </div>
   <div class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
    </div>
   <div class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
    </div>
   <div class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
    </div>
   <div class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css to match:

```
.star{


   display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 8px;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.star:active {
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.star:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    background-image: url("//cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/star.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.star.belowchecked:after {
     content:"";
    display: block;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    background-image: url("//findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/128/keditbookmarks.png");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And jQuery to show the stars:

```
 $(function () {

    $(".star").click(function () {
        var x = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");
        var val = x.val();
        x.attr("checked", true);
        $(".star input[type='radio']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() <= val) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("belowchecked");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("belowchecked");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/33sh3yya/13/)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I only tested it in Chrome.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Tested everywhere and it works. Sorry about earlier. Only Chrome allowed pseudo-elements on inputs for some reason.